# why my CSS did not set the color of div border successfully?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` in my html page which holds 3 radio buttons:

```
<html> 
<head>
   <link href="CSS/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outside">

       <div id="inside">
        <input type="radio"> apple
        <input type="radio"> orange
        <input type="radio"> banana
       </div>

       <div id="others"></div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS is located under CSS directory,

**CSS/mystyle.css**:

```
#inside{

    font-size:12px;     
    border-color:#ff3366;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

The `width`, `height` and `font-size` are set successfully, but the `border-color:#ff3366;` does not shows, why? Why I am failed to set the border color for the div ?

-------------------- MORE ---------------------

By the way, how to locate my inner div (with id="inside") to the right hand side of the outside div, with about 100px margin to the right most border of outside div?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to set a `border-style`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/qRMuQ/

```
border-color:#ff3366;
border-width: 1px; /* this allows you to adjust the thickness */
border-style: solid;
```

This can also be written in the shorthand:

```
border: 1px solid #ff3366;
```

UPDATE: To move `#inside` to the right you need to `float:right` then add a `margin-right: 100px`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/qRMuQ/

```
#outside{
    overflow:auto;
}
#inside{
    font-size:12px;     
    border-color:#ff3366;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right; /* this will move it to the right */
    margin-right: 100px; /* this applies the 100px margin from the right */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question, please check my update of my post

Comment: Note that `border-width` (NOT `border-size`) is the correct name. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width

Answer (score 2):

The color was set fine, you just never actually *added* a border. Try using this:

```
#inside{

    font-size:12px;     
    border-color:#ff3366;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

As to your updated question, make it `float:right` and `margin-right:100px`. The only caveat is, you need to add an extra div after `#other` with just `clear:both` to clear the floated div.

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question, please check my update of my post